# How to add all form's elements on submit in Meteor.js?

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

I'm trying to create an app that saves information after I enter it in input fields! I'm having some problems with adding my form that has more than 1 input field.

These are my HTML and JS files:

```
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';

import { Tasks } from '../api/tasks.js';

import './body.html';

Template.body.helpers({
  tasks() {
    // Show newest tasks at the top
    return Tasks.find({}, { sort: { createdAt: -1 } });
  },
});

Template.body.events({
  'submit .new-task'(event) {
    // Prevent default browser form submit
    event.preventDefault();

    // Get value from form element
    const target = event.target;
    const text = target.text.value;

    // Insert a task into the collection
    Tasks.insert({
      text,
      createdAt: new Date(), // current time
    });

  },
});
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <header>

      <form class="new-task">
        <input type="text" name="text" placeholder="Type to add new tasks" />
      </form>
    </header>

    <ul>
      {{#each tasks}}
        {{> task}}
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

<template name="task">
  <li>{{text}}</li>
</template>
```

Please tell me how could I add more than 2 inputs, and display it by clicking submit-button?

Comment: Hard to understand what is your issue. But did you try duplicate <input type="text" name="text" placeholder="Type to add new tasks" /> replace the name="text" with alternative property name and modify data reference accordingly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really unclear what your problem is. Could this be as simple as just including a second text field and saving it to mongo at the same time as the first field?

html:

```
<form class="new-task">
  <input type="text" name="text" placeholder="Type to add new tasks" />
  <input type="text" name="text2" placeholder="Type to add something else" />
</form>
```

js:

```
const target = event.target;
const text = target.text.value;
const text2 = target.text2.value;

Tasks.insert({ text, text2, createdAt: new Date() });
```

Comment: Your code dosn't work(
Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
    at Object.click .subm (body.js:20)
-const text = target.text.value;-
That strip(

Comment: sorry.
It was my mistake.
Your code works! Thanks)
Change your answer pls-for that:
const target = event.target;
const text = target.text.value;
const text2 = target.text2.value;
Tasks.insert({ text, text2, createdAt: new Date() });
target.text.value = '';
target.text2.value = '';

Answer (score 0):

I would advise to take a look at this awesome package for form management in Meteor: https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform